# Prepopulated database - Android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm having a real trouble in building an android application that has a prepopulated database.

Please take a look at the entire [source code](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6T3Dz5rsfrrYWYwNTZiMzAtOWQ2YS00NjAyLTg0YmUtY2M1ODM4NDNhODdj&hl=en_US).

I created a database by making use of sqlitebrowser and copied it the "assets" directory in my Android application.

I added the code of copying the database from assets directory in a Java Class `DBAdapter.java`

In `MainActivity.java` I called `createDatabase` function so if the database doesn't exist it should copy the database from assets directory. After creating the database I call the `getAllContacts` function and display it on the page.

Whenever I execute the project it throws an error which I'm not able to debug.

Could anyone please help me out to resolve the issue?

**UPDATE:**

Logcat shows the following exception. It seems "contacts" table in assets/MyDB.db is not copied/created but I'm not sure why.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.me.mydb/org.me.mydb.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, email FROM contacts
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
```

Comment: what does logcat said about this...?

Comment: where do I see the logs? Sorry I'm a newbie to Android

Comment: you have to see it on the console manuallyhttp://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html if you use ADT it comes with a Logcat View to see your logs

Comment: Thanks got it.. Here is the logs trace

E/AndroidRuntime(  672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.me.mydb/org.me.mydb.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, email FROM contacts
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(  672):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

Comment: From the logcat it seems that the table "contacts" in MyDB.db is not copied/created.. But I'm not sure how to fix this problem.. Any help??

Comment: Omg! Are you using Google Docs as some kind of versioning control system for your code? Please consider github...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to get your started.

Essentially the idea is to use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and when no database exists you copy a your pre-seeded database byte for byte into the correct location. I have it in a project of mine slightly modified but it works appears to work just fine

Comment: I use this implementation as well and recommend it. However, sometimes it can be a bit fickle and doesn't copy the entire database properly, so make sure you check somewhere in your app that it copied okay.

Comment: @Paul.s I followed the same procedure given in the link.. but it didnt work out. Would be great if you could debug my code and let me know where the problem exist..

Comment: @Espiandev Would it be possible for you to send me the working code/project?

Comment: @Paul.s I created a new project and copied the same code given here http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications">..But I get the following exception I/Database( 425): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
E/Database( 425): sqlite3_open_v2(“/data/data/org.me.mdbtest/databases/MyDB.db”, &handle, 1, NULL) failed
W/System.err( 425): java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyDB.db

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line which says `copyDBFromResource();` with the following code -

```
        SQLiteDatabase readDB = null; 
        readDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        readDB.close();
        readDB = null;
        copyDBFromResource();
```

I think this is needed because your code cannot itself create files in the Data folder, and making a call to `getReadableDatabase()` creates the db file for you there. And Android 2.2 onwards you need to close the database after getting a handle to it otherwise the copy won't succeed.

Edit:

If it still doesn't work, try giving the Write External Storage permission as follows -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Could you try the giving the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (just after the application node in your manifest) as I've described in the edit above ?

Comment: @Abinav where should I add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?  

Should I add in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, right after your application node, inside your manifest node.

Answer (score 0):

Well DataHelper comes with a onCreate method you can create the database there a even populates there.

[Official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29)

> Called when the database is created for the first time. This is where
>   the creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should
>   happen.

in fact you haved override that method

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Yeaaaah I know that it is possible to create database by making use of onCreate function... But what if there are hundreds/thousands of rows that is already created in the database file??

Most of the Android examples and tutorials out there in the web,  create and populate the database at runtime... I'm looking for an example/tutorial which can an independent, preloaded database with the Android application.

Could you please let me know what is the issue in my code??

Answer (score 0):

I use the onCreate event handling and an set of *.sql scripts (executed line-by-line in simple loop).

This is handy when you need also to write a database update routines. I've one sql script to initialize a new (up-to-date) database and a set of sql scripts for each outdated version of the database.

e.g. "create" sql script is called whenever new database has to be initialized, or a chain of scripts "v1-update-to-v2" and "v2-update-to-v3" is called whenever user has to update his database from version 1 to version 3. This is slower than single update script per version (like "v1-update-to-v3" and "v2-update-to-v3") but this "chain" is easier to maintain as I add new versions (I don't need to change anything in the old scripts).